# Limsup and liminf of $(-1)^{n+1}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Prove your assertion.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I’m comfortable finding the values for limsup and liminf of the following sequence.

$$(-1)^{n+1}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

I’m then asked to prove it. How would I go about rigorously proving $\liminf=-1$ or $\limsup=1$

My intuition tells me to use an $\varepsilon$-$N$ argument but I don’t really know where to start as my experience with those is with limits in particular.

I know that limsup, for example, is just the limit as $n$ approaches infinity of the supremum of the tail end of our sequence, but am not sure how to proceed with a rigorous proof

Comment: the sequence is $(-1)^{n+1} + \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ right?

Comment: Yes, important clarification, thx

Comment: notice that the sequence sup{$a_k$ : $k\geq n$} is constant, its $1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...$ and the sequence  inf{$a_k$ : $k\geq n$}  $-1, -1 ,-1, -1, ....$ is also constant, so if you take the limit, you get $1$ and $-1$ respectively. this can easily be proven by $\epsilon- N$ argument because $d(1,1) = 0$ and $d(-1,-1) = 0$

Comment: Hmm, ok. I like that.

Comment: I forgot to mention that  $a_n = (-1)^{n+1}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n} $

Comment: Thanks. Are u able to verify if my logic on the below answer is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to notice the sequence $$(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{n}-1\right) = (-1)^{n+1} +\frac{(-1)^n}{n}.$$

And look at the odd indexed subsequence and the even indexed subsequence.

Comment: Ok, thx. I don’t have an issue finding the values. That’s clear to me, I’m struggling with how to prove it. So, if i claim that the sequence is always $\leq1$ where would i go from there?

Comment: Well if the sequence is bounded by $1$ and $-1$ and you find subsequences that converge to those values then they are necessarily your $\lim \inf$ and $\lim \sup$.

Comment: Ok so creat subsequences of even and odd indices and show that they converge to 1 and -1 respectively

Comment: And then they are necessarily the limsup and liminf?

Comment: Should read odd and even above above

Comment: As long as the limits exist (these do), certainly. A professor might want you to prove that but would not be hard at all.